# Says that my computer is running in low-graphics mode, but cannot run failsafe x. How do I fix this?

Tags: nvidia

When I start up my computer it tells me I am running in low graphics mode. I've read tutorials on how to fix this and they all say I need to run failsafe x. When I try to run failsafe x nothing happens. My screen starts out black and sort of fades to a bluish and then to an orangeish and then to black, but nothing else happens. What the heck is going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1.Goto command console and login with your username and password.

2.enter the command $sudo nano  etc/X11/xorg.conf

3.delete all its content and save the file by pressing ctrl+o

4.exit the file by ctrl+x

5.$sudo reboot